# How to save a HTML FORM data to use in future

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a form to show the data with several buttons like create, edit, copy, delete...... many more depending on the context. For the most of the actions like create, edit, copy.... there are two buttons, save, and cancel. I control the buttons' show/hide by the javascript.

After going into one of the action (such as edit, copy, create etc) if user presses the cancel button, I need bring the user back to there it was started. What is the best way yo save the previous form data so that I don't have to make an AJAX call to the server to fetch the data.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal Working Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem.

Comment: Here is a best way to explain my problem. If you have any comment here, go to Edit your own comment and after making some changes, don't save, you cancel your change. It comes to where it started. How to do it without reading the data from the server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use localStorage of the browser.
[Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Are you suggesting to store the entire DOM of the FORM, or each input values? In either case are there any available tools?

Comment: Only values. It's better for your needs